# Get item from spinner into url

Tags: java, android, url, spinner

I searched for an answer but couldn't find it. 
The problem: 
Depending on the selected spinner-item the application should show a different image.
At this moment I can't get it to work.
The Url works like this: "my.site.com/images/" imc_met ".png" 
were imc_met is the filename. 
I can't get it to work.

Btw the app isn't finished yet

```
package example.myapplication;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;


public class itemsActivity extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button btnSubmit;
private Bitmap image;
private ImageView imageView;
private String imc_met, imc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.items);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

// add items into spinner dynamically
public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

// get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem()!=null){
                imc_met = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

        }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v)  {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("my.site.com"); //here should the right link appear.
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (url != null) {
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
});
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**EDIT**

Please post the whole code needed to be used to make the correct URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener()` twice! The first time (which should get the the item's value) is overwritten by the second time (which is `CustomOnItemSelectedListener`). Thus, the first listener won't be executed.

Remove the `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());`

(When you use `setOnXxxListener()`, only the last call will be used).

Comment: Thanks, this combined with imc = "http://my.site.com/images/"+imc_met+".png"; did it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that your list values returned contains blank spaces in them which are not permissible in URLs.. Try something without spaces...

**EDIT:-** ok.. you havent set and `OnItemSelectedListener` on your `spinner2` and have set 2 different ones on `spinner1`

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

And

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

Comment: The list items used don't have spaces. and I need to know what to do exactly. one of them is simply "dog"

Answer (score 0):

YOu should take one string object and on click of spinner item, assign it the value of it and then just use that in **URL.**

Answer (score 0):

You have set data on spinner2 and added listener on spiner1. spiner1 has no data. Add listener on spiner2 and run it again

Comment: spinner 1 has data as far as I know

Comment: In your code.. i am able to see "list" has set to spinner2 only. Spinner1 does not have any data. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: addItemsOnSpinner2(); in this method you have set data on spinner2. from this line imc_met = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(); you are trying to pull data from spinner1

Comment: well the dropdown menu has data.. the app is working so I've seen that worked. just getting the imageview to show the image doesn't work.

Comment: Ok.. some times high resolution images will not show properly on image view. try to load low resolution images(i.e lower than your target). try it. Just see your log it ll give warnings.

Comment: please check this one also.. imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); whether id is correct or not (if you have more than one image view in your app).

Comment: the problem is the URL not the imageview.